# Sharepoint2010 - How to show latest Announcements from sub-sites onto main site

Tags: sharepoint

we have configured a sharepoint 2010 main site for all corporate users and department wise sub sites for each department need eg. HR, FINANCE, OPERATIONS and other related departments in the company.
every department have different announcements which need to be shown in main site's annoucement webpart.

can any body suggest how we can show latest announcements from each subsites on main site's announcement webpart.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use content query web part, in the tool pane you can customize your query.